# Tortoise came out of hibernation box in the fridge

Tags: safety, tortoises

Yesterday we put our Hermans tortoise in a box in the fridge. When we put him in he was a little agitated at first but settled down immediately. He had spotted eating for a week so we thought it was time to hibernate him,and he was 0.18 on the Jackson scale.

However I just went to check on him and he had crawled out of his box in the fridge and was not moving. I've given him a lukewarm bath and set him under his heart lamp as his shell was very cold. He's still not really moving and I'm very worried.

Is there anything I need to do (except take him to the vet tomorrow)?
Is it ok to not hibernate him, he's 3 years old.

---

### Update

After some nice lukewarm baths, and lots of time under his sun lamp he fully recovered and got a very healthy appetite back and is doing fantastically now.

Comment: What did the vet say? (I know nothing about caring for tortoises, I'm just curious!)

Comment: Unfortunately we are short with money and couldn't take him. We have been giving him warm baths twice a day as I read that helps, and afterwards he had started reading. If we don't bathe him he doesn't go and eat on his own. We've also installed an extra heater we had for his enclosure, and that seems to have also made him happier. I think he just needed a lot of love and attention!